# AppleWatch : On button tap from the the AppleWach Open URL on iPhone device

Tags: iphone, apple-watch

I want to open url from the AppleWatch app button tap to the mobile application. 
Please any one have any idea regarding to these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added this in your AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void(^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply 
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you have to apply on button `tap` in Watch App

```
NSURL *url = // your URL
NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:url, @"URLKey", nil];
[WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:dic reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error)
 {
  NSLog(@"%@ %@",replyInfo, error);
 }];
```

And you can receive this request in iPhone in `AppDelegate.m`

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void(^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply
{
    //receive userinfo dictionary here to perform specific request from watch
    NSString *url = [userInfo objectForKey:@"URLKey"];
    // perform operation on url
    reply(@{@"Notification Alert":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",dist]});
}
```